# Decoding 'code string' to UTF8 and string

Tags: c#, utf-8

First, sorry about my knowledge ...

Above all I have string type value `%B3%F3%C7%F9`.

Since I receive it from other processor, I don't know how it made... (just I receive this string)
What I only know are

1. this is something encoded Korean language (I guess it is `농협`)
2. the encode method is one of `utf-8` or `euc-kr`

What I wnat to do is to decode this strange and coded string to utf-8 string.
(for example, decode `%B3%F3%C7%F9` to `농협` and assign it string type variable)

Thanks for your attention

(I'm working in ASP.NET Core 1.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your % values are basically URL encoding, so %F9 represents a byte value of 249, for example.

So the first thing you need to do is convert this into a byte array. I've done this a potentially inefficient way in my example. Once you've done that, you need to convert that byte array into a string using the EUC-KR encoding type.

```
public static void Main()
{
    string data = "%B3%F3%C7%F9";
    byte[] bData = new byte[data.Length / 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 3)
    {
        int pos = i / 3;            
        bData[pos] = Convert.ToByte(data.Substring(i + 1, 2), 16);
    }
    data = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("euc-kr").GetString(bData);
    Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yUhBxe)

Comment: awesome! it works!! thanks for answer and explaination!